# how to get access to environment variables from output file

Tags: windows, python, sed, awk

I want to get variables from a output file specific
 location,and input file format as below:

```
log1.txt format:
[v] Output Data
<Value>DIMM_A,4096,1600,Hynix,HMT351S6CFR8C-PB,0942E041,1206,01,Hynix,,</Value>

or log2.txt format:
[v] Output Data
<Value>DIMM_B,4096,1600,Hynix,HMT351S6CFR8C-PB,017E90AE,1205,01,Hynix,,</Value>
<Value>DIMM_A,4096,1600,Hynix,HMT351S6CFR8C-PB,012E908D,1205,01,Hynix,,</Value>
```

and we want to get output OUT.TXT file format as below:

```
if log1.txt format and then output file format:
SET DIMM1=DIMM_A,4096,1600,Hynix,HMT351S6CFR8C-PB,0942E041,1206,01,Hynix,,

if log2.txt format and then output file format:
SET DIMM2=DIMM_B,4096,1600,Hynix,HMT351S6CFR8C-PB,017E90AE,1205,01,Hynix,,
SET DIMM1=DIMM_A,4096,1600,Hynix,HMT351S6CFR8C-PB,012E908D,1205,01,Hynix,,
```

---

who could you help to me? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that we don't know how much lines with `Value` we have. Therefore solution is a bit complicated:

```
sed -n '/^<Value/{s/^<[^>]*>/=/;s/<[^>]*>$//;p}' log1.txt | sort | cat -n |\
sed 's/^\s\+\([0-9]*\)\s\+=/SET DIMM\1=/'
```

where the first `sed` greps lines with Value and removes `<>` tags. After that `sort` will sort lines, `cat -n` will enumerate them and last `sed` will move the line number into `DIMM-num-`.

With `awk` it would be pretty close to `sed` solution:

```
awk -F'>' '/^<Value/{gsub ("<.*", "", $2);print $2}' log1.txt | sort |\
awk '{print "SET DIMM"NR"="$0}'
```

Comment: I have tried your command line， but no result output,

Comment: Does your file have the exact format as in example? Try to remove `^` before `<Value`.